# Animation on a view with ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams ends instantly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

I'm currently trying to change the `matchConstraintPercentWidth` from 2 to 0 of a view using `Animation()` when starting my activity (in method `onWindowFocusChanged()` to make sure that all the views have been drawn correctly). The problem is the animation ends instanlty (and th view has now the new params - seems like the duration of the animation is 0 ms), no matter the duration I set...
Here is my code (in Kotlin) :

```
override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
        if (hasFocus) {
            val gradient = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.black_gradient)
            val animation = object : Animation() {
                override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                    val params = gradient.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                    params.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0f
                    gradient.layoutParams = params
                }
            }
            animation.duration = 2000L // in ms
            gradient.startAnimation(animation) //also tried animation.start() without effect
            //animation.hasStarted() is always false here
        }
    }
```

Any help is welcome ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That `applyTransformation` method is where you're meant to calculate the current state of the animation, based on `interpolatedTime` (which is between `0.0` and `1.0`). You're just setting your constraint value to 0, so it's not actually changing a value over time and animating anything.

Honestly you probably don't want to touch any of that if you can help it, Android has some helper classes that abstract a lot of that detail away, so you can just easily animate a thing.[ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation#value-animator) is probably a good shout, you could just do

```
ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0f, 100f).apply {
    addUpdateListener { anim ->
        val params = (gradient.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams)
        params.matchConstraintPercentWidth = anim.animatedValue as Float
    }
    duration = 1000
    start()
}
```

and that should be the equivalent of what you're doing. There's also `ObjectAnimator` at that link too, but that requires a setter method and there isn't one for that layout parameter ([ConstraintProperties](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/widget/ConstraintProperties) has some, but not for that one as far as I can see)

Comment: Thanks ! It's working (but we absolutely have to update and **apply** the percentWidth using `gradient.layoutParams = params` at the end of `addUpdateListener()` ^^

Comment: Ah ok yeah, I was just trimming it down but I don't really know anything about animating the layout parameters! Also if you haven't seen ``MotionLayout``, that might be a good thing to be aware of, see if it fits what you're doing (it's also apparently the new hotness)
 https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/motionlayout

Answer (score 0):

Code looks fine to me, try removing the condition of **hasFocus**, because there might some views which might be getting the focus before the this particular the thing you should do to diagnose is

1. try to log **`hasFocus`** if it's not getting focus then change the code like code below, also just a tip **you should always initialize the views outside of callbacks.**

   ```
    override fun onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus: Boolean) {
                val gradient = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.black_gradient)
                val animation = object : Animation() {
                    override fun applyTransformation(interpolatedTime: Float, t: Transformation?) {
                        val params = gradient.layoutParams as ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams
                        params.matchConstraintPercentWidth = 0f
                        gradient.layoutParams = params
                    }
                }
                animation.duration = 2000L // in ms
                gradient.startAnimation(animation) //also tried animation.start() without effect
                //animation.hasStarted() is always false here
        }
   ```